# Exit current tmux session from command line

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to exit the current `tmux` session from with a pane within this session by using a command line command instead of using the `tmux` keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes run "tmux kill-session" or "tmux kill-server" to kill them all.